How to customize the default metrics in Prometheus for .net
We have an API and services on .NET 8 running in Kubernetes with Prometheus. Currently the Prometheus client library is configured with the default metrics it provides and there are few custom metrics added. As we are trying to reduce the metrics storage, I am looking for a way to customize the default ones: not to completely suppress them, but to remove some metrics, adjust the buckets boundaries and remove some labels. Currently among the default ones there are quite many that we do not need, some overlap in terms of information (http_request_duration_seconds_bucket , microsoft_aspnetcore_hosting_http_server_request_duration_bucket) and the buckets intervals for request duration do not suit us.
On the client library page there is no information if that is possible at all, it is suggested that you can suppress all default metrics. But I will need to add custom ones to track the request duration, the count of requests and few others like current requests, memory, CPU, which seems not that easy.

If you're unable to reconfigure the exporter to exclude metrics, an alternative is to drop the metrics at scrape time

There is no exporter - we use Prometheus client library for .net. Or I do not completely understand Prometheus infrastructure...
I understand this configuration is done on the Prometheus job? And I can skip some metrics: that will be great. But I guess I can only skip metrics, I am also looking for a way to configure the metrics labels

What are you using to collect and expose prometheus metrics in your app? Sounds like it may be prometheus-net, it has a lot of metrics enabled by default. Can you provide your program.cs/startup.cs code ?
